# iPhone SDK - Morning or afternoon

Tags: iphone, date

Can someone help me out with something.

I'm trying to get the current part of the day, am or pm. Is there an easy way of accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jacob and Ira.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, use *NSDateFormatter*:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat: @"a"];

NSLog ([formatter stringFromDate: now]);

[formatter release];
```

Outputs:

> 2009-08-06 14:20:35.538 yourApp [4971:20b] PM

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way .. but this works.

```
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    int hour = [components hour];
    if ( hour > 12 ){
        NSLog(@"PM %d",hour);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"AM");
    }
```

Comment: Oops. A bit slow. Jacob's method is probably cleaner.